# Try/catch a veces no captura Win32Exception en el evento OnClosing (Error al crear identificador de ventana)

Tags: c#, windows-forms, hilos, eventos, try-catch

Estoy usando **Environment.Exit()** en el evento OnClosing para asegurarme de que ningún thread quede zombie al cerrar mi aplicación, y va bien, eso funciona. El problema es que de vez en cuando al cerrar la plicación se produce una excepción que no puedo controlar.

**Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' en System.Windows.Forms.dll**

**Error al crear identificador de ventana.**

He intentado usar Try/catch pero no sirve de nada, la excepción se sigue produciendo.

¿Sabe alguien como puedo manejar correctamente esta situación?

Este es el código que me está dando el problema:

```
public void OnClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{

       if (MessageBox.Show("Desea cerrar el programa?", "Advertencia",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
       {
           e.Cancel = true;
           return;//no salir
       }
        
        try
        {
            Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);//--> aquí se produce la excepción (Error al crear identificador de)
        }
        catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex)
        {
            string message = "AppClose::OnClosing()-> " + ex.Message + " Error code: " + ex.ErrorCode;
            MessageBox.Show(message, "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);                
        }       
}
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: `Environment.Exit()` no necesariamente termina todos los hilos de la aplicación. ¿Estás seguro de que tu programa pueda generar hilos zombie? De no haber dicha posibilidad, ¿para qué preocuparse? En caso que aún quieras hacerlo, ¿no hay una mejor opción?

Comment: Hola, si a veces se me queda algún hilo zombie... casi siempre es por el socket que está bloqueado esperando conexiones de clientes... acabo de encontrar una forma alternativa (https://stackoverflow.com/a/905593) que es marcar los hilos con la propiedad **isBackground**. en vez de usar Environment.Exit()... aún no sé si funciona el 100% de las veces pues solo he hecho 3 pruebas... pero por el momento parece que promete. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Mateo!!

Comment: ¿Tienes la certeza de en qué parte se está bloqueando? Podría ser más fácil evitar que se generen hilos zombi que lidiar con un problema originado para arreglar otro. Corta las cosas de raíz si puedes. Así no tienes que hacer cosas raras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es normal que no te capture esa excepción, al fin y al cabo el código sobre el que haces el `try` no la lanza. Si consultamos la documentación de [`Environment.Exit`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=net-6.0) vemos lo siguiente:

> #### Excepciones
>
> ###### [SecurityException](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.security.securityexception?view=net-6.0)
>
> El autor de llamada no tiene permisos de seguridad suficientes para realizar esta función.

Y es lógico ¿Por qué iba a lanzar una excepción con un error de crear ventanas una función que cierra el sistema?

¿Acaso hay otra parte de tu código que cree ventanas y no esté dentro del bloque `try`? Mi principal sospechoso es el `MessageBox`, que al fin y al cabo es una ventana y no está en el bloque `try`, intenta hacer esto:

```
public void OnClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    try {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Desea cerrar el programa?", "Advertencia",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;//no salir
        }

        Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
    }
    catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex)
    {
        string message = "AppClose::OnClosing()-> " + ex.Message + " Error code: " + ex.ErrorCode;
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!!